# iptables simulator

Tags: networking, simulation

Looking for software under any OS in order to simulate IP table rules, then deploy to real system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never heard of something like this... (Assuming Windows) Have you thought of just using a visual route program such as Nirsoft [NetRouteView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_route_view.html) inside a virtual machine, then deploy do your real system after.

... Alternatively, use your real system and just use this or something similar to export/import in case of error.